# Function handle formats in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, function-handle

A function handles in Octave is defined as the example below.

```
f = @sin;
```

From now on, calling function `f(x)` has the same effect as calling `sin(x)`. So far so good. My problem starts with the function below from one of my programming assignments.

```
function sim = gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma)
```

The line above represents the header of the function `gaussianKernel`. This takes three variables as input. However, the call below messes up my mind because it only passes two variables and then three while referring to `gaussianKernel`.

```
model = svmTrain(X, y, C, @(x1, x2) gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma));
```

Shouldn't that be simply `model = svmTrain(X, y, C, @gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma));`? What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't provide the surrounding code, but my guess is that the variable `sigma` is defined in the code before calling `model = svmTrain(X, y, C, @(x1, x2) gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma));`. It is an example of a [parametrized anonymous function](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions) that captures the values of variables in the current scope. This is also known as a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). It looks like Matlab has [better documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html#bsgprpq-8) for this very useful programming pattern.

The function handle `@gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma)` would be equivalent to `@gaussianKernel`. Using `model = svmTrain(X, y, C, @gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma));` might not work in this case if the fourth argument of `svmTrain` is required to be a function with two input arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The `sigma` variable is already defined somewhere else in the code. Therefore, `svmTrain` pulls that value out of the existing scope.

The purpose of creating the anonymous function `@(x1, x2) gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma)` is to make a function that takes in two arguments instead of three. If you look at the code in `svmTrain`, it takes in a parameter `kernelFunction` and only calls it with two arguments. `svmTrain` itself is not concerned with the value of `sigma` and in fact only knows that the `kernelFunction` it is passed should only have two arguments.

An alternate approach would have been to define a new function:

```
function sim = gKwithoutSigma(x1, x2)
    sim = gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma)
endfunction
```

Note that this would have to be defined somewhere within the script calling `svmTrain` in the first place. Then, you could call `svmTrain` as:

```
model = svmTrain(X, y, C, @gKwithoutSigma(x1, x2))
```

Using the anonymous parametrized function prevents you from having to write the extra code for `gKwithoutSigma`.